# How to remove audio overlay from audio video file

Tags: ffmpeg

I got a video file which has both video and audio. The audio has an overlay of some soft music in a way so that the original soundtrack and dialogues in the video are difficult to hear. I want to remove or suppress this audio overlay.

Is that possible using ffmpeg? I don't know of a ffmpeg command I could have tried to get this done, so am not posting a command. Below is the output from the command "ffmpeg -i videoFile.mp4"

I don't know how to attach videos here, so I have uploaded the MP4 video at below URL:

https://tbrJar.com/videoFile.mp4

Thanks

```
D:\>ffmpeg.exe -i videoFile.mp4
ffmpeg version N-83280-gcba4f0e Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --e
nable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --
enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv
--enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-li
bfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug -
-enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enabl
e-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-li
bsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolam
e --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx
 --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable
-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --ena
ble-zlib
  libavutil      55. 45.100 / 55. 45.100
  libavcodec     57. 75.100 / 57. 75.100
  libavformat    57. 65.100 / 57. 65.100
  libavdevice    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
  libavfilter     6. 71.100 /  6. 71.100
  libswscale      4.  3.101 /  4.  3.101
  libswresample   2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
  libpostproc    54.  2.100 / 54.  2.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'videoFile.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.65.100
  Duration: 00:01:00.93, start: -0.012336, bitrate: 311 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709)
, 540x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 3:2], 175 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc
(default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt
p, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
At least one output file must be specified
```

Comment: No, not possible. If there were two audio tracks being mixed then you could theoretically separate one from the other but it's not the case, it's one track that have been rendered the way it is.

Comment: @ChanganAuto - There is a new "magic" cake unbaker. See below. It can't get a totally clean result from something as obviously scr3wed as this, but I've never heard anything that can do anywhere near as good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what used to be [& often still is] known as "the holy grail of the misinformed". Otherwise known as "unbaking a cake".
Your audio is stereo, the voice track is equally in both sides. Had it been 5.1 you could have separated out the centre channel quite easily. The fact that the voices are buried a long, long way under the music does not help your case in the slightest, I'm afraid.

You won't do this with something like ffmpeg yet. You can't even do it with high-end audio manipulation tools such as Izotope RX. [I had a quick go - I got pretty much nowhere [as expected].

There is one last-ditch attempt using an AI/machine learning structure online - [Adobe Podcast Enhance](https://podcast.adobe.com/enhance) [free but requires signup].
Even it cannot perform miracles. What you have is more music than voice; until recently this has been the audio equivalent of trying to unbake a cake to get the flour back.

There have always been tricks to *eliminate* a single central voice track with simple tools, usually by inverting phase of one side, but there's no real way to accentuate or isolate one.

You'll need to first extract the audio from the video to be able to upload to Adobe. Though I don't speak whatever language the audio is in, I think you may be able to at least tell what it is saying. It's far from perfect & leaves a lot of ring. Running the resulting file through again improves some of the ringing, but doesn't eliminate it entirely. It's still a far better result than I can get with $500 worth of non-AI Izotope. I can't post a finished link, the web page doesn't provide one. You'll have to perform the operation yourself.

*After coments - Background:*… I'm a professional sound engineer of 40 years' experience. I cannot beat the new Adobe AI tool with anything I own, or have ever used before.
This is why this task is known as the "holy grail of the misinformed". People with zero experience beyond watching a few episodes of CSI always think you should be able to just "science it".
You can't.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. Can't I do something with highpass lowpass or firequalizer filters? I understand it won't be in good quality, but something better than what I got will do. Thanks

Comment: Nope. Not a damn thing. That would have been just far too easy :P [background… I'm a professional sound engineer of 40 years' experience. I cannot beat the new Adobe AI tool with anything I own, or have ever used before.] This is why this task is known as the "holy grail of the misinformed". People with zero experience beyond watching a few episodes of CSI, always think you should be able to "science it". You can't.

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. I deeply appreciate. I'm accepting your answer. Thanks again.